# maven generates wrong download url for artifact

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

We have Nexus(`https://maven.mycompany.com/repository/maven-public/`) repository. We have deployed jar snapshot repo

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.my-proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

But another application that uses this dependency couldn't download artifact. I've tried download dependency with command line*(maven version 3.8.4)*

```shell
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:get -DrepoUrl=https://maven.mycompany.com/repository/maven-public/ -Dartifact=com.mycompany.my-proj:my-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT
-P my-repo
```

Suddenly I've noticed that maven builds the wrong download URL as below that `"com."` missed

```shell
Downloading from my-repo: https://maven.mycompany.com/repository/maven-public/mycompany/my-proj/my-app/maven-metadata.xml
```

Then I used quotation marks for `-Dartifact="com.mycompany.my-proj:my-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT"` after that worked and downloaded. I didn't understand what is the problem? This problem also exists in the building of the project.

Comment: First you should use an up-to-date version: `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get` because maven-dependency-plugin 2.1 is really old... https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/

Comment: It doesn't matter, same problem again with `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0`